# Java : Replacing Last character of a String and First character of the String

Tags: java

I want to add Two java JSON String manually , so for this i need to remove **"}"** and replace it with comma **","** of first JSON String and remove the first **"{"** of the second JSON String .
This is my program

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;
public class Hi {
    private static JsonHelper jsonHelper = JsonHelper.getInstance();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Tracker> allCusts = null;

String A = "{\"user5\":{\"Iden\":4,\"Num\":1},\"user2\":{\"Iden\":5,\"Num\":1}}";

String B = "{\"user1\":{\"Iden\":4,\"Num\":1},\"user3\":{\"Iden\":6,\"Num\":1},\"user2\":{\"Iden\":5,\"Num\":1}}";

        String totalString = A + B;
        if (null != totalString) {
            allCusts = (Map<String, Tracker>) jsonHelper.toObject(
                    totalString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Tracker>>() {
                    });

        }
        System.out.println(allCusts);
    }
}
```

When adding two Strings  A + B

I want to remove the last character of "}" in A and replace it with "," and remove the FIrst character of "{" in B .

SO this should it look like .

```
String A = "{\"user5\":{\"Iden\":4,\"Num\":1},\"user2\":{\"Iden\":5,\"Num\":1},";

String B = "\"user1\":{\"Iden\":4,\"Num\":1},\"user3\":{\"Iden\":6,\"Num\":1},\"user2\":{\"Iden\":5,\"Num\":1}}";
```

I have tried

```
String  Astr = A.replace(A.substring(A.length()-1), ",");
String  Bstr = B.replaceFirst("{", "");

String totalString =  Astr + Bstr ;
```

With this i was getting

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition

please suggest .

Comment: I would use a proper JSON deserializer and serializer like http://json.org/java/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{` is a control character for Regular Expressions, and since [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a string representation of a Regular Expression as its first argument, you need to escape the `{` so it's not treated as a control character:

```
String  Bstr = B.replaceFirst("\\{", "");
```

---

I would say that using the replace methods is really overkill here since you're just trying to chop a character off of either end of a string. This should work just as well:

```
String totalString = A.substring(0, A.length()-1) + "," + B.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, regex doesn't look like a very good tool for this. But the following seem to work:

```
String str = "{..{...}..}}";
str = str.replaceFirst("\\{", "");
str = str.replaceFirst("}$", ","); 
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output**:

> ..{...}..},

Comment: I think `str.replaceFirst("}$", ",");` works just fine for the 2nd replace, and it has 4 fewer backslashes.

Comment: @DaoWen: Thanks. Added it to the answer, and that sure does look better. :)

Comment: Java _really_ needs some sort of raw string syntax you can use for regular expressions like they have in Scala and C#. I wrote a regex a little while back that needed **five** backslashes in a row to get the escaping right in Java. Bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in your first two statements. Add `0` as start index in `substring` method and leave with that. Put `\\` as escape char in matching pattern and ut a `,` in second statement as replacement value.

```
String  Astr = A.substring(0, A.length()-1);//truncate the ending `}`
String  Bstr = B.replaceFirst("\\{", ",");//replaces first '{` with a ','
String totalString =  Astr + Bstr ;
```

**Please note:** There are better ways, but I am just trying to correct your statements.